# Define a property based on other properties

Tags: ontology, protege

I want to create an ontology about genealogy. I have the classes Person and Gender and the relation has_child between two Persons and the opposite relation has_parent. Each Person has a Gender. I would like to define some new properties like has_father defined by `has_parent P1 and P1 has_gender MALE` or has_sibling defined by `has_sibling(X1, X2) = has_father(X1, F) and has_father(X2, F)`. For this example, I ignored the mother, but it's for the sake of simplicity.

I could create explicit relations and add them to the Persons, but I want the system to infer the relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found how to do it. I used the property chains mechanism.